# CSS autocomplete for PhpStorm 2021.1

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2021.1 on Mac.

I'm having a problem getting my CSS to give suggestions for class names. I have the CSS file stored locally (no CDN) and it's not auto-completing my CSS when I link my style sheet.

Where do I need set on the Mac version, because I don't have this problem on my Windows machine?

Comment: no special setup is required, this should work out of the box. Do you have any third-party plugins installed?

Comment: Just the default plugins that comes installed. No extra

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching the idea.log (**Help > Show Log in ...**) + a sample project the issue can be repeated with